# How do I add this panels to tabcontrol instead of adding them to the form?

Tags: c#

Here is the code. Help will be much obliged. I want the panels to be added to tabePage1, but it is being added to the form instead.

```
private void tabPage1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    int i, j;
    for (i = 1; i <= 3; i++)
    {
        for (j = 1; j <= 4; j++)
        {
            Panel a = new Panel();
            a.Location = new Point(i * 200, j * 50);
            a.Width = 180;
            a.Height = 40;
            a.Name = "Rom " + (((i * 4) - 3) + (j - 1));
            a.BackColor = Color.Yellow;
            a.AllowDrop = true;
            a.DragDrop += new System.Windows.Forms.DragEventHandler(this.panel1_DragDrop);
            a.DragOver += new System.Windows.Forms.DragEventHandler(this.panel1_DragOver);
            a.Visible = true;
            Label l = new Label();
            l.Location = new Point(10, 10);
            l.Width = 180;
            l.Text = a.Name;
            a.Controls.Add(l);
            l.AllowDrop = true;
            this.Controls.Add(a);
```

Comment: tabPage_Click is probably the wrong event to try and do this with.

Answer (score 1):

This code:

```
this.Controls.Add(a);
```

adds the control to the `Form`, because your `tabPage1_Click` method is in a subclass of `Form` (making `this` refer to the `Form`).  To add the panels to `tabPage1`, do this instead:

```
tabPage1.Controls.Add(a);
```

Incidentally, do you really want to add all the panels to a single `TabPage`, or do you want to create a `TabPage` for each panel?  If the latter, the code will obviously look different.

**Edit:** in answer to your comment, you can add to a different `TabPage` by referring to it by name as above (e.g. `tabPage2.Controls.Add(a);`) or, if you want to add a set of panels to each `TabPage` in your `TabControl`, you could do something like this:

```
foreach (TabPage tp in yourTabControl.TabPages)
{
    // create panel...
    tp.Controls.Add(a);
    // ...
}
```

Comment: thank you! I want to add the same panels to the next TabPage aswell. if you can point me in the right direction, that would be great.

Comment: I hope that i could bother you one last time. I have an drag and drop function. i drag names from a listbox into the panels inside the tabpages. how do i get those names to still be in those panels when i close and open the program ? I am using an xml-file to save the names in the listbox.